# How to hide a code from myself until a specified time

Tags: permissions, restricted-access

Essentially, what I need is some way to generate and store a random string (20 characters long, say) for some period of time, such that there is no way for me to recover the string until the end of that period. I am running standard Ubuntu 12.10.

Things that make this hard:

- I have root access.
- The computer might shut down and start up during the period.
- There needs to be no way for me to recover the string before the period ends.
- I'll have no internet access for the duration of the period.

Some possible avenues of attack:

- Run a program that generates the string and stores it in memory, waits for n seconds, then prints the string. This won't work because the process would be killed if the computer restarted, and I might look in the program's memory to find the string.
- Let the program change the root password to the randomly-generated string, removing root access from me; let it store the string in a file that only root has r/w access to, and let root repeatedly run a program which checks whether the period is over, and if so, give me the string (and thus root access). This sounds like it would work, but removing root access would be inconvenient and I'd have to reinstall Ubuntu every time something went wrong.

The reason I need to do this is that I have an addiction to internet porn. Most of the time I can control it, but I get cravings late at night. This is even harder because I use a computer for my work and I work from home. So lately I've started removing /sbin/dhclient, which disables internet connectivity (until I can get a liveCD and copy the file back, but that takes a while). What I want to do instead is to generate a password for dhclient (by encrypting dhclient, or just creating a zipfile with that password), and then only have the password given back to me the next morning. Basically I'm trying to find a [commitment device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_Device), a bit like an alcoholic pouring his liquor into the sink.

There might be a really easy way to do this that I'm missing - please tell me any ideas you have.

Any help with this will really be appreciated!

Comment: How far would you be willing to go to circumvent this restriction? Your second proposal looks interesting, but there are ways to recover the root password if you lost it or don't have access to it. Basically, if you have physical access to the system, there are ways to regain access no matter what. I guess the question is whether you want to make access just inconvenient or "as impossible as possible".

Comment: It has to be pretty inconvenient. If necessary I can delete all copies of the Ubuntu iso on my computer, and give away all my liveCDs, after I've tested the system. I don't know whether there's a way to get root back without any bootable media. If there is, I think I'd prefer not to know about it.

Comment: You can configure the interface manually, without dhclient. So if you're motivated enough, you could find a way to do that and circumvent something as simple as removing dhclient.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Last time I tried that and failed, but maybe I should deactivate /sbin/iw* and /sbin/if* too, just in case.

Comment: Also asked over here: http://superuser.com/questions/619152/how-to-hide-a-code-from-myself-until-a-specified-time. Is this an example of cross-posting?

Comment: @vasa1 Yes. And this is really an abstract question about how to accomplish a computing-related task. (That is, it is in part an XY problem--the problem does not necessarily come down to string recovery.) Since multi-posting (i.e., cross-posting) on different Stack Exchange sites is basically not allowed, and since the problem is much less related to Ubuntu than to general computing, I recommend keeping this question open on Super User but closing it here. If it's closed here (or there), it could possibly even be migrated there (or here) and merged, so all answers are in one place.

Comment: @EliahKagan, I added my vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

A physical measure may be easier to implement and cumbersome enough to circumvent.

For instance, a proposal would be: Plug in your router and modem into a power strip, plug said power strip into a [timer device](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0026PZQHY) , then lock the entire setup in either a closet or a cupboard, such that only a power and network cable come out (by "network" I mean what you'd plug into the modem, be it a phone line or a coaxial cable). Have someone else (neighbor, relative) keep the key, in case you need to fix things. The timer will control when you have access to the internet. Again, this is possible to circumvent, but cumbersome: unless you have extra equipment, or go into such a rage that you thrash the closet or cupboard to gain access, you should be well-covered and need not mess with the computer itself (which is a good idea since you need it to work).

To implement this entirely on the computer,  first I'd do some research to locate the most low-level component you need to disable in order to remove all internet access (perhaps the network card driver? the ifconfig and ip commands?). Then you could gpg encrypt that component with a randomly-generated symmetric key, and schedule an e-mail to be sent to you later with the key, so you can reenable things. You need some sort of service where once you schedule the e-mail, you have NO way of looking at it or changing it (so something like a calendar reminder may be out of the question). Perhaps one of those e-card services where you can schedule card sending.

Comment: Thanks, the timer device setup looks like it could really work. I'll use that if I can't get a computer-only solution. (I don't currently control my modem, but I could probably get my own.) Your second solution also looks good (I hadn't thought of the e-card idea!), but I won't be able to read the email without internet access.